# NTFS - Allow only one user

Tags: permissions, ntfs, network-shares, active-directory, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to use NTFS to only allow one specific user to a resource?

- I have a shared folder, where I will put user home directories, which allows the "Domain Users" group full access.
- I have a subfolder called Bob and want to deny all but Bob access to this folder.

I tried adding Bob to the security tab, giving him full control and denying the users group. I know this doesn't work so I just wondered if this were possible and, if so, how? I am running Windows Server 2012

Comment: haven't really tried it but i'd guess that if you don't allow "everyone" then it should only allow who you tell it to eg bob.  Perhaps you should give a screenshot showing the permissions and how it isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Deny entries always take precedence over Allow entries. (Not completely true, but true enough.) You need to remove all the Allow entries for other users.

First, open the Security tab for the folder. Press Advanced to open the advanced ACL editor.

[image: advanced ACL editor]

Click "Disable inheritance" to allow the removal of inherited entries.

[image: block inheritance]

Press "Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object." You can now select unwanted entries (the Allow one on Users and Authenticated Users, for instance) and press Remove. I suggest leaving the entries for SYSTEM (because that account is used for various system operations) and possibly Administrators.

Note that, even if you attempt to deny them access, administrators will still be able to take ownership and change the ACLs to give themselves whatever access they want.

You will need to make sure the user has been granted access in the share ACL as well. Open the Sharing tab of the share folder's properties. Click Advanced Sharing, then Permissions.

[image: share settings]

Users are allowed access if and only if they pass both the share and NTFS/file ACLs. If you want to control access only with NTFS (the Advanced Security Settings business we did earlier), just give Everyone everything as pictured.

Comment: @PJMahoney I have updated my answer. Note that access is granted only if *both* NTFS and share permissions allow it.

Comment: @PJMahoney Thanks for the note, it's always a good idea to give exactly what's needed and no more. :) Note that, after Windows 2000, the only difference between Everyone and Authenticated Users is that Everyone includes the Guest account while AU does not.